# Fine-Tuning Pretrained BERT with CNN. How to Disable Masking

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, text-classification, bert-language-model

Has anyone used CNN in Keras to fine-tune a pre-trained BERT? 
I have been trying to design this but the pre-trained model comes with Masks (i think in the embedding layer) and when the fine-tuning architecture is built on the output of one the encoder layers it gives this error`Layer conv1d_1 does not support masking, but was passed an input_mask`

So far I have tried some suggested workarounds such as using `keras_trans_mask` to remove the mask before the CNN and add it back later. But that leads to other errors too.

Is it possible to disable Masking in the pre-trained model or is there a workaround for it?

EDIT: This is the code I'm working with

```
inputs = model.inputs[:2] 
layer_output = model.get_layer('Encoder-12-FeedForward-Norm').output  
conv_layer= keras.layers.Conv1D(100, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
data_format='channels_first')(layer_output)   
maxpool_layer = keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(conv_layer)
flat_layer= keras.layers.Flatten()(maxpool_layer)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')(flat_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(RAdam(learning_rate =LR),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

So `layer_output` contains a mask and it cannot be applied to `conv1d`